How to remove multiple section breaks in google docs
My document is filled with "section break (next page)", how do i remove all of them at once?

does this reference answer your question?

Welcome to Web Applications. Consider registering your account to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. Registering is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see Why should I register my account?
